# Should I use std::unique_ptr<T> in a std::vector member variable in my class?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, smart-pointers, visual-c++-2012

Imagine a `class C` that has a member variable `m_MyList` of type `std::vector` in which I want to store objects of type `MyClass`. `C` has two functions that add or remove objects in `m_MyList`.
`m_MyList` should also be made accessible for consumers of `C` as they need to read the collection of `MyClass` objects. The external reader of the collection will have no means to change the collection, thus the `MyClass` objects are owned only by `C`.

Now my question:
In C++11 style, what is the best T to store in the vector?
The possibilities seem to be:

- `std::vector<MyClass>`
- `std::vector<MyClass*>`
- `std::vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>`, using `std:move` to push the `unique_ptr` into the `vector`

Comment: The `unique_ptr` solution doesn't really buy you anything, unless the objects are noncopyable. The raw pointer version is downright harmful. Just go for the simple solution

Comment: How big of an object is `MyClass` and how many are you planning to store? Will there be a lot of single insertions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the `MyClass` objects are owned by `C`, then the best option would be the simplest:

```
std::vector<MyClass>
```

The only reason I could see for using `std::unique_ptrs` here is if you need to keep pointers to a base class for polymorphism. In this case the unique_ptrs serve the purpose of releasing resources upon destruction of the vector. But then the `C` interface should not transfer ownership to the clients.

Comment: `MyClass` could be an object which is costly to move/copy. Using a pointer allows you to resize the vector without having to copy a lot of memory around.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y that is true, but it is independent of ownership and clients and so on, so I assumed that consideration to be beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: The other reason to use any kind of reference type as member of a class is to make sure the header don't expose details of that members, while the unit file (cpp) does know about it. It is good for isolation actually. Here the vector require that MyClass be defined before the member is defined. So you have to include MyClass code. In some cases, you don't want that. That being said, it have a  different memory and management costs, so the choice is very context specific.

Comment: @Klaim the problem is that, in the case of `unique_ptr`, whether a complete type is needed or not is not a completely trivial issue, see [here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/incomplete.html).

Comment: @juanchopanza I know, but you can still easily fix it with defining constructors and destructors in the cpp and using =default if you don't want to write it.

Answer (score 12):

Raw pointers (`std::vector<MyClass*>`) are incorrect if C owns the objects. The other two are pretty similar with the following trade-offs:

- `std::vector<MyClass>` - requires MyClass to be copyable and/or move-able
- `std::vector<unique_ptr<MyClass>>` - requires (additional) dynamic allocations

The kind of operations being performed on the container may also be relevant. To take an extreme example, if MyClass is large and the container is being repeatedly shuffled, `unique_ptr` would be the better choice.

Comment: Every element of a `std::vector` is placed on the free store, so saying "requires dynamic allocations" like it's a bad thing is kind of a misnomer here...

Comment: @rubenvb: the vector only requires one dynamic allocation at a time (or briefly 2 during reallocation). Hence it doesn't require dynamic allocationS ;-) If `MyClass` is small enough, you'll notice the difference eventually. I suppose it might be better to say, "requires more overhead in dynamic allocations". It's a bad thing if you're typing extra code for the sole purpose of wasting memory. It *might* be a bad thing if `MyClass` is nothrow constructible, and you introduce dynamic allocations in places they wouldn't otherwise happen, thus introducing exceptions.

Comment: Dynamic allocation of each individual object not only takes more memory, it increases fragmentation and causes more data cache misses. In most code, it will be entirely unnoticable but like Steve says - don't type more to make the code slightly worse.